# Stop decreasing stock quantity when an order is placed

Tags: product, orders, stock, inventory

I need to stop decreasing the stock quantity when an order is placed and reduce the stock only on successful payment because there are lot abandoned transactions on my site. I found an article to do this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/132/protx_form_-_subtracting_stock_on_successful_payment), which says how to credit back the quantity to the product on redirect action and the decrease it on successful response action. Is there any other way to do this?

Also I am running a cron to cancel the abandoned orders. When the orders are cancelled the quantities get added back to product stock.

My problem is if I follow the above link to decrease stock only on successful payment, how do I skip the product stock being updated when an abandoned order is cancelled?

Comment: james.i can give you solution ...but important.this stock of deducated when you have goes to success page.Cofirm ths

Comment: @AmitBera Is there a way to skip the stock being added back when an order is cancelled?

Comment: by default magento is do this,if order is cancel

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite this? Because if we deduct the stock at success page as per your method and the cron cancels any abandoned orders the quantity will be added back to the product stock which will spoil the product inventory. As I mentioned in my question there will be lot of abandoned transactions in my site. If I use your method with the problem of order cancellation be solved?

Comment: i guess that your order place time from return from online payment is less than cron time then it works perfectly for you

Comment: can you post your solution so that i can try that?

Comment: just give me time.i am working on some task...i will give u solution within 2hrs.

Comment: An option would be to release these orders using a batch script after xx minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I soved my problem 
Reff: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/132/protx_form_-_subtracting_stock_on_successful_payment

I have 2 payment menthods 1) CCavenue and 2) COD. I only wanted to stop the stock decrease  to be done only on the CCavenue orders, so I used this.

The stock is credited back to the system when the customer is redirected to the payment gateway using this code.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['updated']) || $_SESSION['updated'] != $session->getLastRealOrderId()) {

            $items = $order->getAllItems(); // Get all items from the order
            if ($items) {
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    if ($item->getParentItem()) { 
                        continue;
                    }
                        $quantity = $item->getQtyOrdered(); // get Qty ordered
                        $product_sku = $item->getSku(); // get it's sku
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$product_sku);
                    if($product){               
                        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product); // Load the stock for this product
                        $stock->setQty($stock->getQty()+$quantity); // Set to new Qty           
                        $stock->save(); // Save
                    }
                }
            }
            $_SESSION['updated'] = $session->getLastRealOrderId();
            /* end stock addition */
        }
```

I added this code in the `redirectAction` in the `paymentController.php` of the payment extension. And in the `responseAction` I added the below code which re-deducts the stock when the payment is successful.

```
$items = $order->getAllItems(); // Get all items from the order
if ($items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {

        if ($item->getParentItem()) { 
            continue;
        }
            $quantity = $item->getQtyOrdered(); // get Qty ordered
            $product_sku = $item->getSku(); 
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$product_sku);
        if($product){

            $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product); // Load the stock for this product
            $stock->setQty($stock->getQty()-$quantity); // Set to new Qty           
            $stock->save(); // Save
        }
    }
}
```

Most of my products are configurable products. When I tried to get the item details from the order items collection it was giving me two values one for configurable and the other for simple product. Since I wanted to reduce the stock for only simple product I used SKU in the above codes to load the simple product.

My other problem was the cron I was running to cancel the abandoned transaction orders credits the stock back to the system when the order is cancelled. To fix this I copied *app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php* into 
*app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php* and modified the `cancel` function to this so that the stock won't get credited back the abandoned orders are cancelled.

```
if ($this->getStatusId() !== self::STATUS_CANCELED) {
    $order_status = $this->getOrder()->getStatus();
    if($order_status != 'abandoned_payment'){
        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_item_cancel', array('item'=>$this));
    }
    $this->setQtyCanceled($this->getQtyToCancel());
    $this->setTaxCanceled(
        $this->getTaxCanceled() +
        $this->getBaseTaxAmount() * $this->getQtyCanceled() / $this->getQtyOrdered()
    );
    $this->setHiddenTaxCanceled(
        $this->getHiddenTaxCanceled() +
        $this->getHiddenTaxAmount() * $this->getQtyCanceled() / $this->getQtyOrdered()
    );
}
```

***abandoned_payment*** is my order status for the abandoned orders.

Comment: Could you refactor into a module? Putting this code into the controller files is not good practices.

Comment: @SwiftOtterStudios the controller I used is the one in my custom payment module.

Comment: Ok. I was curious, so thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Magento

Create an module which  prevent to stock deducate when order place using event  checkout_submit_all_after  and function

Mage_Cataloginventory_Model_Observer

**Step1:** Create file `config.xml at app/code/local/Amit/Preventstock/etc/`
 and code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Preventstock>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Preventstock>    
    </modules>
    <global>

        <models>
            <preventstock>
                <class>Amit_Preventstock_Model</class>
            </preventstock>
        </models>   
    </global>

    <frontend>

                <!-- event to prevent to stock deducate when order place -->
        <events>
                <checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <observers>
                        <prevent_stock_minus_on_order_place>
                            <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                            <method>revertQuoteInventory</method>
                        </prevent_stock_minus_on_order_place>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_submit_all_after>
        </events>   
    <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <stock_deducated_on_success_page>
                        <class>preventstock/observer</class>
                        <method>triggermyevent</method>
                    </stock_deducated_on_success_page>  
                </observers>                
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <final_qty_reduce_on_checkout_sucess>
                <observers>
                    <at_last_qty_reduce_event>
                       <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                        <method>checkoutAllSubmitAfter</method>     
                    </at_last_qty_reduce_event> 
                </observers>
            </final_qty_reduce_on_checkout_sucess>      
        </events>   
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

**Step2:** `Observer.php` code at

```
app/code/local/Amit/Preventstock/Model
```

and code is

```
<?php
class Amit_Preventstock_Model_Observer{
    public function triggermyevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $order_ids=$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if(!is_array($order_ids)):
            return;
        endif;
        foreach ($order_ids as $eachOrderId) {

            $Order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($eachOrderId);
            $Quote=Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($Order->getQuoteId());

             Mage::dispatchEvent('final_qty_reduce_on_checkout_sucess',
                array('order'=>$Order, 'quote'=>$Quote));

        }


    }

}
```

you need create  Amit_Preventstock.xml at app/etc/modules and my

**Code only work on fronted not backend**

***If you  have any issue let me know at any time***

Comment: Thanks. But where are revertQuoteInventory and checkoutAllSubmitAfter methods used?

Comment: @AmithBera I think you missed out some code while pasting it here

Comment: Does in this case the customer have to visit success page? Or does a payment confirmation via Api that sets order to status new also trigger it?

Comment: it decrease qty whenever customer is come to success page